# iOS NSStream connection seems to pause

Tags: objective-c, networking, tcp, network-programming, nsstream

I'm trying to send data between two iOS devices using example code from http://code.google.com/p/iphonebits/source/browse/trunk/src/TicTacToeNew/

The client connects well, and data is transferred between the two devices just fine.  The client sends packets of data about 10 times/second. However, I'm getting very odd pauses between data being received.

In the receiving code, I'm putting a debug statement every time a request is received :

```
- (void) stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
     NSLog(@"stream: handleEvent : %d", eventCode);
         switch(eventCode) {
            // ... handle event and print out received data
         }
}
```

The relevant send code is in the sendQueuedData function here: http://code.google.com/p/iphonebits/source/browse/trunk/src/TicTacToeNew/Classes/OnlineSession.m?r=19

The first  second or so of requests goes as planned (although it seems to batch requests together):

```
2011-03-13 12:28:08.759 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":1.98,"y":0.01}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":1.98,"y":0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":2.11,"y":0.01}
2011-03-13 12:28:08.781 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":2.07,"y":0.03}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":2.02,"y":0.03}
2011-03-13 12:28:08.923 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":1.98,"y":0.01}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":1.86,"y":0.01}
2011-03-13 12:28:08.996 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":1.73,"y":0.01}
2011-03-13 12:28:09.171 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":2.38,"y":-0.56}
2011-03-13 12:28:09.182 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:09.332 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:09.496 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:09.501 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:09.598 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
```

... but then notice the time stamps on the subsequent calls:

```
2011-03-13 12:28:10.163 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:13.770 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}    
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:13.772 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:13.777 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:13.868 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:14.016 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:14.177 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:14.340 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:14.424 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:15.065 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:16.338 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:18.740 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
2011-03-13 12:28:18.741 bluetoothmodule[52188:207] stream: handleEvent : 2
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
[DEBUG] Fire Event: data: {"x":0.00,"y":-0.00}
```

As you can see, the handleEvent() callback is being called sporadically, and is obviously not suitable to a real-time application.  Does anyone know why? Should I be switching from using NSStreams to something like http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/ with UDP?

Comment: @Joe Blow - I was testing on iPhone 4.  I actually did switch to using AsyncSocket, it's a bit better, but still sporadic.

Comment: Seeing this as well and have yet to find the culprit of the problem.